# Minification-safe catch parameter in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, webpack, bundling-and-minification, terser

After minifying my JavaScript application using webpack's Terser plugin, this catch function does not run correctly in the browser

```
        .catch((error)=> {
            vm.loginError = true;
            vm.loading = false;

            if (!error || !error.error){return};

            if (error.error.indexOf('user exists')) {
                <!-- expecting this line to run when error.error contains "user exists" but this line is never executed -->
                vm.emailTakenError = true;
            } else {
                vm.serverGeneralError = true;
            }
        });
```

In this example, the back end sends an error object containing an error property set to "user exists".

```
{"status":"error","error_message":"user exists","error":"user exists"}
```

The browser should be able to parse the error object and read error.error, but it cannot.

Using un-minified code, the script works correctly and the browser executes the "vm.emailTakenError = true" line.

In the browser console command line, after minification, returning error.error gives this error (Chrome Dev Tools):

Uncaught ReferenceError: error is not defined
    at eval (eval at  (signup.ts:92), :1:1)

Strangely, using source maps on the minified code in Chrome Dev Tools, the console can parse the error.error property using mouseover, but not as a Watch nor in the browser window nor any other method.

Also mysteriously, this line never runs:

```
if (!error || !error.error){return};
```

The code also fails in Firefox.

Do I have a problem with the minifier, with the code, or with something else? How to solve this?

Comment: `error.error.indexOf('user exists')` is incorrect if you’re checking whether the string exists. Should be `error.error.indexOf('user exists') !== -1`. It’s unclear whether this is related to your minification problem, since it shouldn’t even be working unminified.

Comment: Are you sure this is where the error is coming from? What’s the original (non-source-mapped) stack trace on the error? `eval` can definitely mess with minifiers, and it shouldn’t be anywhere in your code. Not even if templates are involved or something.

Comment: Thanks @Ry. error.error.indexOf('user exists') !== -1 Solved it. Coincidentally, this string was at position 0 in our minified code, but not in the non-minified code, a feature of the different environments.

Answer (score 1):

Mystery solved, thanks to @Ry.

The problem was a combination of environments and minification.

In the local (non-minified) environment, the backend service passes a different string to the catch function

```
error.error.indexOf('user exists') == 148 // true
```

In our Staging/Prod environment, we get a different results, a quirk of our server.

```
error.error.indexOf('user exists') === 0 // true
```

So `error.error.indexOf('user exists')` returns a falsy value, so the condition fails.

Next, the `debugger` statement does not work in minified code, at least not in this case.